execution not executed by maven-deploy-plugin
I have to deploy an assembled zip artifact to maven remote repository. zip artifact is created using maven assembly plugin. I defined maven-deploy-plugin in the project pom.xml as follows:
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-release-repo</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <packaging>zip</packaging>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
                            <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagement.repository.id}</repositoryId>
                            <url>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</url>
                            <skip>snapshots</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-snapshot-repo</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <packaging>zip</packaging>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip</file>
                            <repositoryId>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.id}</repositoryId>
                            <url>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}</url>
                            <skip>releases</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

When i run mvn deploy:deploy-file goal from command line, i always get error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.0:deploy-file (default-cli) on project app-pce-testhub: The parameters 'file', 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.0:deploy-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
how to resolve this error?

Please [edit] your question to include the output of the mvn deploy:deploy-file command with the -X argument. Also include the full pom.xml file and if possible a [mcve].

Why are you using deploy plugin via deploy-file  instead of just mvn deploy? How is the zip file being created? Via maven-assembly-plugin ? Why so complicated? Can you give more background information what the purpose of this setup is?

running mvn deploy:deploy-file with -X  did not output any extra information.

zip file is created using maven-assembly-plugin

What i figured out is for configuration to be effective when plugin goal is called directly from command line, name of the execution id has to be default-cli. with this restriction, we can have only one execution configuration in pom.xml.
So now the question is,  is there a way to have multiple executions get executed when plugin goal is called directly from command line.

Why using calling goals directly instead of using the life cycle as I mentioend (and asked before)... mvn deploy will do the right thing?

@khmarbaise - mvn deploy did it for me after some tweak in the pom file. what i was trying to do was not possible or not very straight forward with mvn deploy:deploy-file
